# FlowLayoutPanel bottom inner spacing

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

So I'm having troubles making my FlowLayoutPanel work the way I want.

When adding multiple controls to it so that vertical scroll appears and when scrolled to bottom I don't want controls to be touching the bottom border of FlowLayoutPanel.

---

Padding works properly for all but the bottom side, controls are properly spaced away from the edges of the FlowLayoutPanel, I don't know why bottom is special.

I need a solution that does not include adding invisible/transparent controls to it.

The closest I got to what I want was lowering the clientsize by some amount, but then in that area control doesn't repaint so it shows parts of added controls forever.

Comment: It's not the Padding you have to set, it's the Margin (the child controls'). Padding = Internal spacing, Margin = External spacing. You can also have a mix of FlowLayoutPanels and TableLayoutPanels. See the notes here: [Center multiple rows of controls in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103) and here: [Remove Row inside TableLayoutPanel makes a layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225457/7444103). The latter includes a test Form.

Comment: @Jimi I already had margins on them, anyway, I now just put bigger bottom margin on the last child control to fix it. So I guess that's the solution, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of fixed with with larger margins on child controls, so I'm closing this.