# When TableLayoutPanel activates scroll, FIRST row grows too big

Tags: winforms

I'm going crazy with this. I have seen many threads of people asking to solve when the last row of the TableLayoutPanel grows too big. But I have the opposite problem, when the scroll gets activated because the table has many elements (added programatically), the first row grows too big, the size of the table, and the rest of the rows look just fine. Any help would be appreciated please.

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Read the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103), first *section*. If you don't have any other *custom logic* applied to the scrollbars functionality/scrolling events, it usually work just fine.

Comment: This one is connected to the first: [Remove Row inside TableLayoutPanel makes a layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225457/7444103), but you can find a couple of methods to add/remove rows that may come in handy.