# Resizing TableLayoutPanels when row collapsed/hidden

Tags: winforms

I have a form which has a TableLayoutPanel with 6 rows like this:

[image: default view]

Each label MouseClick event toggles the visible property of the panel below it (which resides in a separate row).

Which makes it look like this:

[image: top panel collapsed]

As you can see only the last row expands upwards to fill the now available space.

If I collapse the bottom or middle row, the row/s above do not expand downwards:

[image: bottom panel collapsed]

How can I make the following happen:

- Visible rows will expand equally to fill the available space
- Rows will move/expand downwards

I've tried all sorts of combinations with the row Absolute/Percent/AutoSize properties... But guessing this might need expansion of the TableLayoutPanel class?

Comment: You need: 1) All Labels.AutoSize = False, Dock = Fill (set the initial Width to the maximum size of these panels) 2) All TLP Rows set to AutoSize. 3) The TLP Column SizeType = Percent = 100%  4) TLP.AutoSize = True, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink. That's all. The notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103) may be useful.

Comment: If you set the Columns/Rows styles in code, clear the existing styles before setting your own.

Comment: Are you sure that should do what I'm hoping? Because that's how I have it setup, I even double checked and redid it to make sure, but when I collapse the third panel, the first and second panels do not expand downwards to fill the space now available

Comment: Using these settings, done in 30 seconds: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/7yNkIos). Did you anchor/dock the TLP, by chance?

Comment: Ah - that's not the functionality I'm trying to describe. That's what I've got already. What I'm trying to achieve is that if you collapse panel 3, everything above it will expand downwards so that panels 1 and 2 expand fill the extra space that panel 3 used to occupy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a working example.

Put a panel on the form and anchored it all directions.

Put the tablelayoutpanel in the panel, set whatever size and anchor it all directions.

Put labels in rows 0, 2, 4.
Set label autosize = true.

Put panels in rows 1, 3, 5.
Anchor the panels in all directions. No docking or autosizing.

Set the tablelayoutpanel rows with labels to absolute and whatever height. I used 20 pixels.

Set the panel rows to Percent 33.33. The table automatically scales it to total 100% if you're under or over.

Label click events:

```
 Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click


        If TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1).Height > 10 Then
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1).Height = 2
        Else
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1).SizeType = SizeType.Percent
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1).Height = 33.33
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

        If TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3).Height > 10 Then
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3).Height = 2
        Else
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3).SizeType = SizeType.Percent
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3).Height = 33.33
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

        If TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5).Height > 10 Then
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5).Height = 2
        Else
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5).SizeType = SizeType.Percent
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5).Height = 33.33
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I don't know if you need to put it in a panel to make it work. You could probably anchor it to the form and be fine.

You could also do this in one event handler by getting the row of the label clicked and adding 1.

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly how I was trying to get it to work. I think what I was missing is that I needed to get the RowStyles rather than just hiding the panel. I didn't put my TableLayoutPanel in another panel; as long as it's anchored I think it works.