# FlowLayoutPanel row height issues

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I want to add dynamic buttons inside the FlowLayoutPanel.
The outline is:

```
      {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = string.Format("button_{0}", i);
            btn.Width = 160;
            btn.Height = 50;
            if ((i) == 4)
            {
                btn.Height = 90;
                btn.Width = 326;
            }
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            if ((i) == 3)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(btn, true);
            }
        }
        flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
```

The problem is the second row  too height.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocbBk.jpg)

the main window is sizeable。

Comment: That's because your "button_4" has a greater height than "button_3". This is just how flowLayoutPanels work (at least the ready ones in yout tool box).I don't think you can change this behaviour.

Comment: You could add a Flow Layout Helper (©™):.e.g., move `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);` before the `if` conditions. Then add the Helper in `if (i == 3)`, after `SetFlowBreak()`: `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Size = new Size(flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width - btn.Right, 1) });`. Or you can do something like this instead: [Center multiple rows of controls in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103)